# Add a UIView to a ScrollView for paging

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, xamarin.ios

How can I have a `UIScollView` content be the content from a `UIView`? I want to design the app layout in a `UIView` and then lay that view into a `UIScrollView` that is connected to a `UIPageControl` for pagination. So when the user swipes to the side, the next view is displayed. I have a sort of idea on how I would accomplish this, but I want to get it right without wasting a lot of time.

Heres my DetailViewController:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;

using UIKit;
using Foundation;
using CoreGraphics;
using CloudKit;

namespace RecordStorePro
{
    public partial class DetailViewController : UIViewController
    {
        public Record DetailRecord { get; set; }

        public DetailViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
        {
        }

        public void SetDetailRecord (Record record)
        {
            if (DetailRecord != record) {
                DetailRecord = record;

                // Update the view
                ConfigureView ();
            }
        }

        void ConfigureView ()
        {
            // Update the user interface for the detail item
            if (IsViewLoaded && DetailRecord != null) {
                //label.Text = DetailRecord.Album;
            }
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad ()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();
            // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

            NavigationItem.SetLeftBarButtonItem (new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.Stop, (sender, args) => {
                NavigationController.PopViewController(true);
            }), true);

            ConfigureView ();

            //this.scrollview.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Gray;

            // set pages and content size
            scrollview.ContentSize = new SizeF ((float)(scrollview.Frame.Width * 2), (float)(scrollview.Frame.Height));
            //this.scrollview.AddSubview ();

            this.scrollview.Scrolled += ScrollEvent;
        }

        private void ScrollEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.pagecontrol.CurrentPage = (int)System.Math.Floor(scrollview.ContentOffset.X / this.scrollview.Frame.Size.Width);
        }

        public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning ()
        {
            base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning ();
            // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
        }
    }
}
```

So when I swipe the screen, I want a subview that contains some labels and textfields to come in and replace the original labels and textfields. It works properly so far except I can't figure out how to add the subview, and make it size appropriately to different screen sizes.

**EDIT**

Heres the problem Im facing now, the views laying in the ScrollView act funny and are about 44f too tall so they let me drag up and down. i tried setting all kinds of constraints as well as manually setting them to -44 smaller with no help. heres a picture of the problem now:

[image: New Problem]

Heres the screenshot of my constraints set.

View A:
[image: View A]

View B:
[image: View B]

ScrollView:
[image: ScrollView]

Nib view:
[image]

Comment: can  you please show us what you tried and what actually want to do ??

Comment: @SubhashSharma I updated my question, hopefully it will make more sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you might want to try these steps:

1. The view that shows the first page will be called *View A*. The view that shows the second page will be called *View B*.
2. Add both views to the Scroll View.
3. <kbd>Control</kbd>-drag from View A to the Scroll View in the sidebar.
4. Hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> and select `Top Space to Superview`, `Bottom Space to Superview`, and `Leading Space to Superview`. Next, press <kbd>Return</kbd> to add those constraints.
5. Make sure those constraints’ constants are set to `0`.
6. <kbd>Control</kbd>-drag from View B to the Scroll View in the sidebar.
7. Hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> and select `Top Space to Superview`, `Bottom Space to Superview`, and `Trailing Space to Superview`. Next, press <kbd>Return</kbd> to add those constraints.
8. <kbd>Control</kbd>-drag from View A to View B in the sidebar.
9. Select `Horizontal Spacing`. Make sure its constant is `0` and its `Second Item` is `View A.Trailing` and its `First Item` is `View B.Leading`.
10. <kbd>Control</kbd>-drag from View A to View B in the sidebar. Select `Equal Widths`. Make sure the Constant is `0`.
11. <kbd>Control</kbd>-drag from View A to the Scroll View in the sidebar. Select `Equal Widths`. Make sure the constant is set to `0`.
12. In the inspector, check “Paging Enabled.” [image: Under the Scrolling header in the Attributes Inspector]

Comment: So then how to I add all my labels and content? Do I do it after adding the views? Or before?

Comment: Probably after. However, if you already had your content views in a containing view or view controller, you can just put that one in.

Comment: Will the constraints still function properly?

Comment: If the constraints don’t reference views outside the containing view, they will still work. Otherwise they will disappear.

Comment: Ok, so I followed all the steps, and now when I run it in the simulator, I don't get anything displaying. I changed the View A BG color to blue and B to red so I could tell the difference, but neither show up.

Comment: Alright, so I found out why it wasn't displaying. I set the height to equal height of the ScrollView, and equal height on ViewA and ViewB, but now the scroll view moves everywhere instead of just paging left and right, its almost as if I can just drag things and the bounce effect work everywhere.

Comment: Edited my answer to fix this.

Comment: I have both scrolling and paging enabled. I'll have to check my constraints on the scroll view

Comment: Would disabling “Bounces” under the “Bounce” heading fix it?

Comment: I was thinking that too. Ill try it when I get a chance. I think I might have forgot to set the height of the scroll view also, so maybe that did it too.

Comment: Bouncing fixed it partly, but now Im having a weirder problem. I think the heigh is whats not working properly

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the constraints so we can see what the problem is? (i. e. select “View A” and take a screenshot)

Comment: Do you want them for each view? Or just View A & B

Comment: Just 1 view should do.

Comment: OK. Could you post a screenshot of the view layout in the nib? This is puzzling.

Comment: Sure can. (Sorry for the late reply)

Comment: I think the problem might be that you have no bottom constraint for the scroll view. Try getting rid of the `Equal Height to Superview` constraint on the scroll view and adding a `Bottom Space to Bottom Layout Guide` constraint. The problem is that the view *shouldn’t* occupy the full height of the superview. If you want the scroll view to extend under the the navigation bar, I will edit my answer with steps.

Comment: Thank you! The other problem that needed to be fixed was the VIEW A and B were set to equal the superview, which when removed fixed the oversize problem!!

Answer (score 0):

> Adding subScrollView with no pagingEnabled to each page and controls into subScrollView works! If you add controls directly to scrollview with paging enabled, it seems gesture recogniser's first responder is always scrollview so your controls never gets the event and behave like a disabled!
>
> UIScrollView has a property called “pagingEnabled”
>
> In Interface Builder, resize the scroll view to allow for some space below it for the page control. Next, drag in a UIPageControl from the library, centered below the scroll view. Resize the UIPageControl to take up the full width of the view.

Comment: I already have that setup, now I need to add all my content like labels and images and design, but I don't want to add it all in code, but just a little if needed. I prefer doing the layout in interface builder.